# Wicket: Multiple feedback panels in one page?

Tags: wicket, feedbackpanel

Can I have multiple feedback panels and determine somehow which one belongs to what?

When I tried to add more than one, all validation messages go to all panels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an `IFeedbackMessageFilter` as you found out by yourself. As for the negated filter mentioned in your answer, I suppose you want to catch any previously undisplayed message in a final `FeedbackPanel`. This can be archived using a FeedbackMassagefilter with the following accept method:

```
public boolean accept(FeedbackMessage message) {
    return !message.isRendered();
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice! That's what I really need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. It's possible to filter the messages going to the feedbackpanel using `IFeedbackMessageFilter`:

```
this.feedbackPanel.setFilter( new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(this) );
```

Still, I need some kind of negating filter for the other one.

Comment: If you just need this negated then why not simply implement a decorator which negates the return value of accept()?

Comment: See Nicktar's answer, "negating" was inexact; I need to pick up "the rest" (think of 3 or more feedbacks).